# What does Sync Do in Team Explorer?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am currently in a project that uses **TFS Git** as the code repository. In Visual Studio, under *Team Explorer* -> *Sync*, there is an option called **Sync**. Now I am familiar with the Fetch, Pull, and Push actions but Sync is new to me.

Any ideas what this does behind the scenes?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Git in Visual Studio, VSTS, and TFS is **standard Git**.  Although **Sync isn’t a Git command**, some GUI environments provide a sync button to both **update your local files** and **push your local changes to your remote** (your hosted repository).

[image]

> The **Sync** button is available on the **Team Explorer** pane and and
>   also displayed after you create a commit using the extension. The
>   **sync tool** enables you to select how you want to update the project:
>
> - **sync**: performs a `git pull` and a `git push`.
> - **fetch**: performs a `git fetch` which retrieves any commits on from your remote without merging them.
> - **pull**: performs a `git pull`.
> - **push**: performs a `git push`.

You can also navigate to the **Synchronization** view from the Changes view by choosing **Sync** immediately after making a commit.

[image]

Comment: Assume user adds a character 'x' to the file on line 1. Then the user clicks on the fetch button, which gets the server version (say character 'y' on line 2), still keeping users local changes. Then the user does a commit followed by a push which pushed both x and y to the server. Now, since 'y' was previously already pushed by someone else (that's the reason we did a fetch), does the history mention that the latest push contained both x and y?

Comment: Isn't it more than just a pull/push? I recall it bringing up a UI for me to merge changes once. I don't often have to merge, but I came here wondering about how exactly this part of the process works (in detail).

Answer (score 17):

Sync is a combination of a Pull Command followed by a Push command. It will 1st perform a Pull, and if there are no conflicts, will then Push the current branch. It is meant as a quick way to just get your current branch into sync with the remote branch.

Comment: Why push back after the pull?  I like to think "Get Latest Version" and let it overwrite so I know I have the latest code from the server.